# How to get Initiator Chain in CefSharp?

Tags: cefsharp

I am trying to retrieve the request initiator chain with CEF, the same one you see in the browser's developer tools - when you go to Network and then click on Initiator tab, but I cannot find this information.
More specifically:

first I tried overriding IRequestHandler.OnResourceLoadComplete, my callback does get called at each URL loaded by the page and I do have access to IBrowser and IRequest, I can find the request's referrer, but using the referrer to rebuild the tree of URL's is not giving me the same results I see in the browser's Initiator Chain.
I then used the DeveloperTools.Network.EnableAsync, I installed my handler for Cefsharp.Devtools.Network.NetworkClient.RequestWillBeSent callback, it gets invoked for every GET request and I do get the IRequest and the Initiator objects, but again they do not contain the information I need to build the Initiator chain. In many cases the Initiator URL is empty, in other cases it's just the main domain of the website.
As an example, if I browse slashdot.org I see this Initiator Chain in the browser (Chrome or Edge):

hzzp://www.slashdot.org

```
+-> hzzps://www.slashdot.org
    +-> hzzps://slashdot.org
        +-> hzzps://a.fsdn.com.sd.classic.css?e97300f6d7a821a0
            +-> ...
        +-> ...
        +-> hzzps://d3tglifpd8whs6.cloudfront.net/js/prebid/slash-homepage/slash-homepage.min.js
            +-> ...
            +-> hzzps://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/tag/js/gpt.js
```

Here, the browser tells me that hzzps://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/tag/js/gpt.js is initiated by hzzps://d3tglifpd8whs6.cloudfront.net/js/prebid/slash-homepage/slash-homepage.min.js.
However, in CEF, when I try to retrieve this information via the referrer URL or the Initiator URL I get "hzzps://slashdot.org", which is not the same initiator as the browser shows me. This happens to almost all URLs, not just this one.
So, if I try to build the Initiator Chain using Referrer url or Initiator url, I am not able to get the same tree that I see in the browser.
How can I get the same initiator chain as the browser via the CEF APIs?
Or, more generically, how can I get the information to build the exact same Initiator Chain as the browser?